# Get Text from a HTML a-Tag with e specific class

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to get the selected text. In my Case; just 'Banana'!
I dont want to get 'It's yummie'!

My **HTML Code:**

```
 <ul>
    <li class="static"><a tabindex="0" class=
        "static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href=
        "/de/SitePages/info.aspx"><span class=
        "additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class=
    "menu-item-text">Orange</span></span></a></li>

    <li class="static selected"><a tabindex="0" class=
        "static selected menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-core-listMenu-selected ms-navedit-linkNode"
        href="/de/SitePages/wt.aspx"><span class=
        "additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class=
        "menu-item-text">Banana</span><span class="ms-hidden">Its
    yummie</span></span></a></li>

    <li class="static"><a tabindex="0" class=
        "static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href=
        "/de/SitePages/pw.aspx"><span class=
        "additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class=
    "menu-item-text">Apple</span></span></a></li>

    <li class="static"><a tabindex="0" class=
        "static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href=
        "/de/SitePages/bt.aspx"><span class=
        "additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class=
    "menu-item-text">Grapes</span></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

My **jQuery Code**

```
var v = $('a', 'li.selected').first().text();
```

The following **Code Returns:**

> BananaIt's yummie

I just want to get '**Banana**'

How can I do this?

Comment: $(a li.selected .menu-item-text).first.text();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the class **".menu-tem-text"** to your jQuery code:

```
$(a li.selected .menu-item-text).first.text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following instead:

```
var v = $('.menu-item-text', 'li.selected').first().text();
```